# Listener interface isn't working with onClick for cardviews in a recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, interface, onclicklistener

I have several cardviews on my layout. When one gets clicked it should call my Listener's onClick method which will start EquationsActivity and pass it the position of the card. That is not working. My recyclerFragment is in a tablayout. I've looked and looked and I can't seem to figure out the problem! All suggestions are appreciated!!

My recyclerAdapter:

```
public class recylcerAdapter extends       RecyclerView.Adapter<recylcerAdapter.ViewHolder> { 

    private Listenerr listener;
    private int[] imageIds;
    private String[] nameArray;



    public interface Listenerr{

        void onClick(int position);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


        private CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(CardView v){
            super(v);
            cardView = v;

        }
    }


    public recylcerAdapter(Context context, String title, Cursor cursor, int[]imageIds, String[]nameArray){

        this.imageIds = imageIds;
        this.nameArray = nameArray;
    }

    public void setListener(Listenerr listener){ 
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public  recylcerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        //create a new view
        CardView cardView = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_main, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cardView);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position){
        //set the values inside the given view

        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon);
        Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position]);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        imageView.setContentDescription(nameArray[position]);
        TextView textView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
        textView.setText(nameArray[position]);

        cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                if(listener != null){
                    Log.v("hitsOnClick", "It has been hit");
                    listener.onClick(position);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        //return number of items in the data set
        return nameArray.length;
    }
}
```

My recycler fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    new listPop().execute();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.recylcler_layout, container, false);


    recylcerAdapter RecylcerAdapter =
            new recylcerAdapter(getActivity(), "Geometry", cursor, imageArray, names.toArray(new String[names.size()]));
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(RecylcerAdapter);

    RecylcerAdapter.setListener(new recylcerAdapter.Listenerr() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EquationsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(EquationsActivity.POSITION, position);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    return recyclerView;
}
```

EDIT:
with more looking I have found that when I tap on a card, the onClick in the onbindviewholder is not being hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's setup the click listener when you create new view holder:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    CardView cardView;
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(CardView v){
        super(v);
        cardView = v;
        imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.list_icon);
        textView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
    }
}
```

And modify a little bit when binding and creating:

```
@Override
public  recylcerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    //create a new view
    final CardView cardView = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_main, parent, false);
    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                if(listener != null){
                    Log.v("hitsOnClick", "It has been hit");
                    listener.onClick((int)cardView.getTag());

                }
            }
        });
    return new ViewHolder(cardView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position){
    //set the values inside the given view

    Drawable drawable = holder.cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position]);
    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    holder.imageView.setContentDescription(nameArray[position]);
    holder.textView.setText(nameArray[position]);

    holder.cardView.setTag(position);
}
```

Comment: Non-static field "listener" cannot be referenced from a static context. That error occurs where you create new view holder. Any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: I made private Listenerr listener  static and then I ran it and the clicks still did not work.

Comment: ^^^^ Can you fix the issues in these comments?^ @anhtuannd